# pull.setDocIds() couchbase lite android

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I can use pull.setDocIds (); no couchase 1.4? In push.setDocIds it works fine.

```
             List<String> docIDs = new ArrayList<>();
                            docIDs.add("mensagem");
                            URL url = new URL("http:/" + hostAddress + ":5432/banco144 ");
                            final Replication pull = database(EscolherAplicativoActivity.this).createPullReplication(url);
                            pull.setDocIds(docIDs);
                            pull.start();
                            pull.addChangeListener(new Replication.ChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void changed(Replication.ChangeEvent event) {
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported for pull because it requires server side cooperation.  It will only work with CouchDB on the backend, not Sync Gateway.  The .NET version will log a warning when you use it, but I don't know if the Android client will.

Comment: eu utilizo no Android perr to peer. that is also true?

Comment: I don't believe peer to peer supports it either, but you have the advantage that you control both the "client" and "server" side in that case so you could set up a "push only" scenario.